# How to avoid logging in at every turn

Tags: windows-server-2012, authentication

We are using a virtual machine to do all our work. I have to log on to it as domain user, which is not a local admin on the virtual machine.

IT department gave me a local admin user. Almost everything I have to do on the vm (which is my whole job) requires admin. So I have to log in (as the local admin user) 90 billion times a day to get my job done. Ok, only 80 billion, but still...

How can I get around this?

Comment: Why can't you logon using the local admin user account?

Comment: Is your domain account not an Admin on all the VM's that you log into ? Also you ask your IT for better solution around this rather than superuser

Comment: @Twisty, I will try that and report back. At the end of the day probably. Thanks.

Comment: Issues specific to corporate IT support and networks are off topic, see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Please talk to your IT department.

Comment: @Davidpostill, I'll remove the references to the it dept.